# In C , "at" sign after i print a string

Tags: c, string, insert

I wrote a function that insert a sub-string in a string at the position 'i' but i have problem . When the position i ={ 1 or 2 or 3 } , after I print the final string , an '@' sign appears at 'i' positon

```
 void insert_sir(char *s , char inserted_s[20] , int pos )
{
    char result_s[30] ;
    strncpy(result_s,s,pos - 1);
    strcat(result_s,inserted_s);
    strcat(result_s,s + pos - 1);
    printf("%s",result_s);

}
```

Comment: are you trying to insert into `s` or `result_s` ? `result_s` is uninitialized you shouldn't copy chars somewhere in the middle of it

Comment: into result_s . Do I need to initialize result_s with " " or NULL? (I'm new to C strings)

Comment: I used just 5 character long for compilation .If I use pos = 4 for example it works fine .

Comment: I initialized result_s = "" and it works .

Comment: if you modified the posted code so that result_s is declared as `char result_s[30] = "";`  That is not quite correct as it is only setting the first byte of `result_s` to a NUL byte.   Suggest: `char result_s[30] = {'\0'};`  as that will set all the bytes of `result_s[]` to NUL rather than just the first byte.

Comment: the question needs to post the input string(s) the expected output string and the actual output string.   Otherwise the question does not comply with the parameters of stackoverflow for a question about a runtime problem  I would also strongly suggest showing the code that is calling this function, so we know exactly what is being passed as parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your char array or you'll get random data from memory. You can easily use the `memset()` function to fill the array with the same character. In this case, I fill it with nulls so that the printf only outputs the desired text since null is the standard termination character.

```
void insert_sir(char *s , char inserted_s[20] , int pos )
{
    char result_s[30] ;
    memset(result_s,0,30);
    strncpy(result_s,s,pos - 1);
    strcat(result_s,inserted_s);
    strcat(result_s,s + pos - 1);
    printf("%s",result_s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the 'memset' trick . I'm new to C strings and your advice helped me !